# Adding password protection and encryption to AutoCAD

Tags: .net, visual-studio, encryption, autocad, autocad-plugin

Since Autodesk did away with password protection in its suite of products. Is there simple way to mimic the data encryption via a plugin in .NET/Visual Basic? I know that the previous versions used Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v.1.

Do I need to get all the rata data that needs to be encrypted first?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement such a feature on the file level, there are many libraries in .NET, then extend the SAVE and OPEN command to encrypt and decrypt the files *on the fly*. But that can be tricky if the person that receive the file don't have your app (or plugin) running. So *out of the shelf* solution may have this already.

Here are some suggetions from [Autodesk Knowledge Network](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-4E32143C-AA81-4A4E-9191-B32C4AA259EE-htm.html).

> Beginning with AutoCAD 2016-based products, the ability to add
>   passwords to drawing files was removed. Instead, we recommend that you
>   purchase an encryption product that meets current industry standards
>   and is updated as needed. For AES symmetric encryption, security
>   experts currently recommend the 256-bit protocol. For RSA asymmetric
>   encryption, they usually recommend the 2048-bit protocol as the
>   minimum for general security and the 4096-bit protocol for internet
>   transactions.
>
> It is recommended that you consider one of the following alternatives
>   to protect drawing files that contain sensitive information:
>
> - Output the drawing as a PDF file, and add a password to the PDF
> - Package the drawing in a ZIP file, and add a password with a secure    external utility
> - Use a third-party password and encryption utility    with, for example, 256-bit AES technology or equivalent
> - Protect the drawing behind network permissions
> - Protect the drawing behind    Autodesk 360 or other cloud provider permissions